# Execute multiple scripts in parallel using shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Usually I start two different gearman worker in different terminals using python command, once those gearman workers get ready, I execute client file which send request to both listening workers.

I was trying to put all three command in shellscript and execute them in one go, but could not

```
#!/bin/sh
python /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_allClass/classifier_allClass.py
python /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_lessClass/classifier_lessClass.py
python ans_type.py 1
```

which gives:

```
folders = [f for f in sorted(listdir(container_path))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_pylink/trec_data'
```

after that I tried to put this python command in `.sh` in same directory and executed shellscripts

allClass.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_allClass/classifier_allClass.py
```

lessClass.sh

```
python /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_lessClass/classifier_lessClass.py
```

and in final.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sh /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_allClass/allClass.sh
sh /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_lessClass/less_lessClass.py
python ans_type.py 1
```

final.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sh /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_allClass/allClass.sh
sh /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_lessClass/less_lessClass.py
python ans_type.py 1
```

which gives:

```
sh: 0: Can't open /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_allClass/allClass.sh
link-grammar: Info: Dictionary found at /usr/share/link-grammar/en/4.0.dict
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Why is '/root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_pylink/trec_data' in root's Desktop rather than in _your_ Desktop? What does `readlink -e /root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_pylink/trec_data` print?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is that the workers are being executed one after another and not at the same time. When you start all three python-scripts in different terminals as before, they are executed concurrently. You might want to try starting the three scripts in one bash-script but with three different subshells.
i.e.:

```
( python path/to/first/worker/FirstWorker.py )
( python path/to/second/worker/SecondWorker.py )
( python path/to/client/Client.py )
```

According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html , you call a subshell like that. Maybe it would even be helpful to start all of them in the background with `&` like so:

```
( python path/to/first/worker/FirstWorker.py ) &
( python path/to/second/worker/SecondWorker.py ) &
( python path/to/client/Client.py ) &
```

You can even redirect the workers' output but I am not exactly sure how to do that... Hope it helps...

Comment: thanks, but already tried this, issue is it could not locate the path being accessed in `FirstWorker.py`, gives error like `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Desktop/karim/temp_git/ATD_final/ATD_pylink/trec_data'`